# Storing descriptive keywords in an MP3's ID3 tags

Tags: mp3, standards, organization, id3

I know I'm not the first, but I'm an audio pack rat who keeps their collection meticulously organized.  Having tried a range of tools, there are holes and time sucks that bug me.  I've started in on the project to build the software that I wish existed.

My question centres around a feature that I hope will cut down on the time it takes to build play lists.  Over time, I want to gradually attach generic keywords to my MP3's.  For example, when I'm listening to an album suitable for programming, I'd like to attach keywords like "ambient" and "no lyrics" so that I can just search by those descriptions later.  Unfortunately, I'm having troubles finding any established conventions for how people might already be doing this.

Are there dedicated ID3 tags for this purpose? (I found none in the spec)

Is there an alternative metadata strategy I should look at?

To be clear, my intention is to bake the keywords into the MP3 somehow.
I'll handle any searches through a database, but I want this info to move easily to other devices and pre populate easily if I change/upgrade the manager.

If this isn't something that people do already, I'll just roll my own solution into a custom/comment tag, but I'd really prefer to leverage any existing momentum.  My pie in the sky hope is a central database of these keywords to save everyone the effort of tagging their collections.

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or a piece of software that could do it? I suppose ID3 tags do not support keywords by themselves - see [this thread for MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=71681), which otherwise supports all kinds of tags. But having e.g. a software that would use comments for this purpose would be useful.

Comment: I reached a similar conclusion as that MediaMonkey thread - I had to manage the tags as DB entries within my app then output them as parseable string into the comments field in the ID3 tags.  ie. artist_tag1, artist_tag2|album_tag1, album_tag2|track_tag1, track_tag2.  Feels ugly, but it suited my purposes.